# Can you link two processes in Erlang if the current process is neither one?

Tags: erlang

It is possible to call `link(pid)` in Erlang to link the currently executing process to the process identified by `pid`. Is it possible to link a process to another if it is not currently executing?

Comment: What do you mean "not currently executing"? If the process **exists** then you can link to it, what ever its state and if it doesn't exist then you can't. As @P_A wrote using `spawn_link` you can create a new process and link to it. You can not link two **other** processes together, you can only link yourself to another process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot.

You can only [`link`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#link-1)/[`unlink`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#unlink-1) from a current process to another one. If the other process is not alive, you will get a `noproc` error (if you are trapping exits) or receive an exit signal (if you are not trapping exits or if the other process was on another node).

You can also use [`spawn_link`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#spawn_link-1) to spawn and link in one atomic operation.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [spawn_link](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#spawn_link-1) fun.

> link is created between the calling process and the new process, atomically.